# How can I add a new text line in Azure DevOps comments after a code block?

Tags: azure-devops, comments, line, codeblocks, addition

How can I add a new text line in Azure DevOps comments after a code block?

I added a code block, populate it with some code and now I want to type some text under the code block. But when I press Enter I am only getting a new code block line added. I tried pressing `Shift + Enter` and it keeps adding a new code block line. I tried focusing the pointer under the code block and right clicking, still the code block remained focused and no new line was added.

E.g. I want to add some text under the code block containing the `my code`:
[image]

And I created it using the `Code` button:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just press `Enter` two times and that should do it.

[image]